# How to find out that the set, of points at which two continuous functions are equal, is open or not?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In this question option C and D are algebra of continuous funtion. They are correct.

For option A i used the following result- "If $f$ is continuous function on set of real numbers and $f(r)=0$ for every rational number $r$, then $f(x)=0$ for all real $x$."

But I am unable to decide anything in option B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$. The set becomes $\{0\}$ which is not open.

Actually (d) is also false. Take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$. Then $h$ is not continuous.

Comment: oh wow......I just typed the exact same answer. :3

Comment: Yes.. I realized it immediately after putting the comment that's why i deleted it. By the way thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Option B is probably false based on what I remember of my Real Analysis courses. To see this, simply consider the functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=0$ on the domain $D = (-1,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Clearly, only $\{0\}$ is in the set. And we know that for the general metric (not discrete metric) on $\mathbb{R}$, a singleton set is always closed.